# ImportError: cannot import name "backend"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

***Below the written code,***

```
from __future__ import print_function
import keras
from keras.datasets import mnist
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Flatten
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
from keras.layers import backend as k


batch_size = 128
num_classes = 10
epochs = 12
```

***and below the issue,***

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d1183f2cea73> in <module>
      8 from tensorflow.keras.layers import Conv2D
      9 from tensorflow.keras.layers import MaxPooling2D
---> 10 from keras.layers import backend as k
     11 
     12 

ImportError: cannot import name 'backend'
```

**Need help to solve this issue**

**Note:** I am using **Python 3.6.0**.

Comment: Have you configured Keras to use the TensorFlow backend (instead of Theano)?

Comment: What versions of tensorflow and keras?

Comment: @Matthew How should I configure keras with tensorflow ? Please healp  me. And I am using created environment as py36. because I it was to difficult to install tensorflow and keras where I used Python 3.7 . That's why I create new environment where python version is Python 3.6.0 .  I should say that when I need any tools thenI install that. as scikit-learn etc.

Comment: Its just a typo, it should be import keras.backend as K

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the keras backend lib

```
import keras.backend as k
```

or directelly from tensorflow

```
from tensorflow.keras import backend as k
```

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling Tensor Flow and keras and removing their directories in site-packages then reinstalling them.

Comment: First you should pip uninstall then the two modules

Comment: I am using created environment as py36. because I it was to difficult to install tensorflow and keras where I used Python 3.7 . That's why I create new environment where python version is Python 3.6.0 . I should say that when I need any tools thenI install that. as scikit-learn etc. I faced problem to use based director that's why I create new environment in anaconda navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
pip install qiskit==0.31.0
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).